# how to perform listing item in react from user input in react in this form eg: {user1:[name,name2],user2:[name3,name4]} using input field

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, arrays, nested-lists

not able to list nested items how can I pass the key value from the map method to add the item to that particular key value and how to map that value in nested form

I want to get the key value of the 'li' inside the submit handler ... like onclick of the trigger popup I want to get that particular value on which the popup is triggered through which I can add the value of the array to that particular key

```
    const addPackage=(e)=>{
        let A2 =e.target.value
        setItem(A2)
    }

    const submitPackage=()=>{
        console.log(Object.keys(folder))
       // over here I have to pass the value that on the popup triggers inside the map method   
       folder[val].push(item)
      console.log(folder) 
    }
 
    return(
        <div>
            <h2 className='header'>drag and drop list</h2>
            <div className="compA">
            <strong>compA</strong><br/>
            <Popup trigger={<touchable>file</touchable>} position="right top">
         <>
             <table bgcolor='white'>
             <tbody>
             <tr><td><strong>create package:</strong></td></tr>  
             <tr><td><input type='text' onChange={addItem}/></td></tr>
             <tr><td> <button onClick={submitValue}>create</button></td></tr>
             </tbody>
             </table>
         </>
         </Popup>
         <hr/> 
           {Object.entries(folder).map((li)=>{return(
           <div align='left'  key={li}>
                    <Popup trigger={<touchable ><FaFolder/>{li[0]}</touchable>} //the li[0] value should assign ass the val over the submit handler
                        position="right top">
                            <>
                            <table  bgcolor='white'>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr><td><strong>package:</strong></td>
                            <td><input type='text' defaultValue={li[0]}/></td></tr>
                            
                            <tr><td><strong>create class:</strong></td>
                            <td><input type='text' onChange={addPackage}/></td></tr> 
                        
                            <tr><td><button onClick={submitPackage}>create</button></td></tr> 
                            </tbody>
                            </table>
                            </>
                            
                    </Popup><br/>
                      
            </div>)
        })}
            </div>
            <div className="compB">

            </div>
            
        </div>
    )

}
export default Input
```

Comment: please any help if your answer is helped will be appriciated

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: over in first popup i creating a object with empty array .. in the second popup i want to add new value to the particular object which onclick of the element gets pop so that nested item should add to that particular object only

Comment: The code is not complete. You should add the full code. With the current code, we get 2 functions and a return statement. But it's missing information. `folder` definition. Better to create a working sample with your code at [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/)